# Angular routerlink complex object as param

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routerlink

Good evening,

I'd like to know the best way to pass a complex object using [routerLink] directive, and how to read it.

ie:

```
complexObject = {
  x : 'ok',
  y: { 
        a: 2,
       b: 'test'
      },
}

<a [routerLink]="['/example/example-test', complexObject ]">

this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(complexObject => {
complexObject.get('x') // ok
complexObject.get('y') // The nested object 'y' is a string like [object object]
 }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Good morning,

This is the solution that I could found:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/example/example-test', { complexObject: complexObject} ]">

this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
            const complexObject = JSON.parse(params.get('complexObject'))
        })
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Good Evening,
One of the way to pass nested object in the routerLink directive is by using JSON.stringify().

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.obj = JSON.stringify(this.complexObject);
}
```

[Convert the complex object by using JSON.stringify() method and pass the object in RouterLink directive.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ufhga.png)

```
<a [routerLink]="['/categories', { complexObject: obj} ]">CLICK</a>
```

[Here we will pass the stringified object to the routerLink directive.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNYJB.png)

```
this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
  const complexObject = JSON.parse(params.get('complexObject'));
});
```

[Extract the object passed in route by using JSON.parse() method.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAer5.png)